# Environment Variables and Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, ide, visual-studio

I have a problem with Visual Studio 2012 and Environment Variables under Windows 7.
I added a variable called `{LIBS}` with the value `C:/libs/`.
In `C:/libs/` are folders containing C++ libraries.

So far, so good. I added the paths to the project's settings (linker etc.), like `{$LIBS}boost` to include the boost libraries.

I expected that I would now be able to use something like this

```
#include "boost/someboostfile"
```

but this does not work, I have to use the absolute path

```
#include "../../boost/someboostfile
```

but this is what I do not want to do.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use angle brackets- `#include <boost/someboostfile>`.